# Adding a record to mysql reusing a phpbb connection

Tags: mysql, sql, command, phpbb

I have integrated PHPbb to my website and I am using the phpbb connection to read data from an additional table I created on the database. below is the read code to query the databse:

```
$sql = 'SELECT tetsin, prod_desc_short, prod_price_old, prod_price_new, prod_img
   FROM ' . tet_product;
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
        {
        $data[] = $row;
        }
```

What I am having trouble with is finding the function to add records to the databse, can someone direct me on what technology I may be using and unaware? I saw something about the Data Absraction layer and was a little more than sketchy on if there are some "variants" on functions or something like that, anyway I know the quer function above is "$db->sql_query" so any help in the insert query would be greatly appriciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the official wiki, it has guides to most things you will need https://wiki.phpbb.com/Queries_in_phpBB3